# Showing that no current flows in some direction, given $\sigma_{ij}$ and that $J_i=\sigma_{ij}E_j$.

Tags: tensors, electromagnetism

> The current $J_i$ due to an electric field $E_i$ is given by
>   $J_i=\sigma_{ij}E_j$, where $\sigma_{ij}$ is the conductivity tensor.
>   In a certain coordinate system, $$(\sigma_{ij})=\begin{pmatrix}
> 2&{-1}&{-1}\\ {-1}&2&{-1}\\ {-1}&{-1}&2\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Show that there is a direction along which no current flows.

Honestly I'm not really sure what I'm meant to show, obviously that there is a direction along which no current flows, but I'm not sure what that 'means', I understand the sentence, but I know what it corresponds to showing, if that makes any sense.

If possible I would ask for a full solution, just so I can study the answer to help me approach the other question, but anything is helpful.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: To measure a component of the vector $J$, you form the scalar product of $J$ and a given direction vector (e.g. $J_1=\mathbf{e}_1^T J$.) In the present case, you want to find a direction along which no current flows i.e. the relevant scalar product vanishes. Is there an obvious such direction vector?

Comment: Can you find a non-zero vector for which $\sigma E=0$?

Comment: It turns out that, no matter how you choose your electric field $E = (E_1, E_2, E_3)$, the direction of the resulting current $J = \sigma E$ is confined in a plane (independent of $E$) so that no current flows toward the normal direction $\mathbf{n}$ of this plane. Can you identify the direction $\mathbf{n}$ ?

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes I thought to form a scalar product, but couldn't find the right vector. Just now I have tried simply $(1,1,1)$ which I believe works, but it wasn't 'obvious' for me, if it's even correct that is.

Comment: That's right. What makes it 'obvious' (always a dangerous word) is that each column sums to zero. Hence $(1,1,1)$ is a left-eigenvector of $\sigma$ with eigenvalue zero.

Comment: @Semiclassical Ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

To sum up the exchange in comments:

We want to find a direction along which there's no current flow, regardless of the particular electric field. But the component of $J$ along some direction vector $n$ is given by the scalar product $n^T J$. So we want $n^T J=n^T \sigma E=0$; for this to be true regardless of the electric field $E$, we require $n^T \sigma=0$ i.e. $n$ should be an eigenvector of $\sigma$ with eigenvalue $0$. (Strictly it's a left-eigenvector; but $\sigma$ is symmetric, so this distinction doesn't matter.) By inspection, one sees that $n=(1,1,1)^T$ is such an eigenvector and we conclude that there is no current flow in this direction.

---

An perhaps more 'physical' approach is to consider a few choices of electric field $E$, and see if there's a common direction with no current flow. For instance, if $E=(1,0,0)^T$ then $J=(2,-1,-1)^T$; if $E=(0,1,0)$ then $J=(-1,2,-1)^T$. In both cases, there will be no current flow in a direction perpendicular to $J$. Hence the cross product of these two resulting currents, $(2,-1,-1)\times(-1,2,-1)=(3,3,3)$, will be perpendicular to both currents.

So there's no current flow in the direction of $(3,3,3)$ for either of these electric fields. To confirm that this holds regardless of $E$, we note that when $E=(0,0,1)^T$ we have $J=(-1,-1,2)^T$ which is perpendicular to $(3,3,3)^T$. So $(3,3,3)$ is perpendicular to $J$ whenever $E$ is any basis vector, and by linearity we conclude that it's true for any $E$. So we conclude that there's no flow in the direction defined by $(3,3,3)^T$, which is the same as that defined by $(1,1,1)^T$.